# Desktop shortcut to Outlook template with user input

Tags: shortcuts, microsoft-office-2010, templates

In essence, I am trying to combine these two questions:
[Configure a Windows shortcut to prompt for input](https://superuser.com/questions/400378/configure-a-windows-shortcut-to-prompt-for-input)
[Can I make a shortcut to Send Outlook Email from Template?](https://superuser.com/questions/606914/can-i-make-a-shortcut-to-send-outlook-email-from-template)

I have three people that I am constantly sending emails to, and the majority of the contents stay the same. I am trying to create three desktop shortcuts, one for each individual, that would open an outlook template to the recipient, and prompt for the three fields that change.

Is this something that can be done with Windows 7 and Office 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured this out by now, but if you navigate to the folder where your template is and drag it to your task bar *on top* of the Microsoft Outlook application, it will stay pinned.

Then, whenever you right click on Outlook your template should be there at the top of the list!

[image]